# Planning for migration to version 7

Tags: migrations

I am just taking on responsibility for a Drupal 6.2 site. It has some custom modules and some quite poorly organised code which I am working with developers to improve alongside developing new features to the site. And being fairly new to Drupal I am just getting my head around how it all hangs together.

One of the things I want to assess is when we should be planning to migrate to Version 7.

1. Is it a reasonable assumption that, as a commercial website, we *should* upgrade to version 7 as support for 6 drops away over the next year or so?
2. Is it possible to develop and refactor on version 6 in such a way to make that migration as painless as possible when we get to it?
3. Is there anything else I should consider as I plan the development roadmap over the next 12 months?

Comment: I posted some quick thoughts below. I could probably expand a bit, but let me know if you have any questions on my answer, and I'll try to take them into account as I update.

Comment: Unrelated to the actual migration. If your site is actually running 6.2, you have some serious security problems you need to handle ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Should you upgrade?**

All contrib modules will slowly shift major version. If you don't follow suit, you risk needing to re-invent the wheel more often than otherwise necessary. Most module maintainers have since long ago shifted focus to D7. A few have even begun maintaining their D8 version.

D6 will become unsupported, and have no more security updates after D8 is released.

**How do we make it painless?**

I don't think there's an answer that can be applied across all sites, but here are some general guidelines.

1. Features needs to be "[released](http://drupal.org/node/1014522)" (warning, lots of reading), and then upgraded by their providing module, and finally re-added to their respective features.
2. Use the [Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) module to easily test getting content over.
3. If possible, *run both versions at the same time*. Hide the fact as well as you can, possibly using a [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy). This is non-trivial to accomplish, but ensures that when you move your last piece of functionality from D6 to D7, parts of your D7 site has been live for a long while already, and you know that it's stable. As one quick example of a relatively general measure one can take to ease this, [Entity API](http://drupal.org/project/entity) can allow you to redefine where an entity reads/writes its data.
4. Often Contrib-space will solve a common problem that Core later decides to incorporate. Switching to these techniques for problem solving everywhere it's relevant will allow you to "partly" upgrade a current DX site to DX + 1, making the gap during the complete upgrade much smaller.
   Two examples of this are below, but this list could probably be much longer:

   1. Use [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) and [Page manager](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) instead of modules like [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) and [Spaces](http://drupal.org/project/spaces). The Pm+P approach to site building is the foundation of a huge re-write of core for D8.
   2. Use [Guzzle](http://drupal.org/project/guzzle) instead of [Http Client](http://drupal.org/project/http_client). Guzzle is the official http-client for Drupal 8.

**Anything else?**

Nothing that comes to mind at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the reading .. interesting stuff. Yes, I have been thinking about running both versions. Whether using a reverse proxy as you suggest or other methods, a problem I am seeing in Drupal having to split data across two different databases/schemas. Unless I am missing a way around this?

Comment: No, you're right, hence the "non-trivial" note. There's a large number of things one can do to make it easier, but what exactly can be done will depend greatly on the site itself. I added a brief note on entity api in the answer, with regard to this.